# is there a way to make chalkboard paint without using waterbase paint

Tags: painting, repainting

Is there a way to make chalkboard paint using oil paint instead of water based latex paint?  I would add the unsanded grout of course , just 2 tbsps. to a cup of paint.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I don't see why not.  I would even consider doing that with epoxy or LPU, which will clean off much better.  The way an average Joe gets brush/rollable 2-part epoxy paint (without going to a chandlery) is *garage floor paint*.